# Synchronizing dates between 2 calendars

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have two calendars on a form where the first reflects only the days of the week and the second that shows the whole month.

What I like and need a lot is that by clicking on the first calendar, for example on the 20th, this value was updated in the second calendar and the same with the second calendar, if you click on the 10th of a given month the first calendar assumes this day too. That is, vice versa. This would be to synchronize these calendars and if possible when advancing with the full calendar the weekly would be modified as well. Attached is the image of these calendars if anyone can give a force there thank you very much, because I sincerely do not know how to do this.

CALENDÁRIO 1:

```
var calendarPicker1 = $("#diaCall").calendarPicker({
    useWheel: false,
    callback: function (cal) {
        // Convertendo data
        dataI = cal.currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        document.getElementById('from_date').value = dataI;
    }
});
```

CALENDÁRIO 2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        document.getElementById('from_date').value = dataAgenda;
    } 
});
```

[image]

Comment: If you aren't married to that datepicker you could try this one.  It has an example linking two calendars.  https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers

Comment: Guys, what I need is this:
Let calendar 1 be updated by selecting a certain calendar date 2. That is, if I click on day 20 on calendar 1 then calendar 2 is already marked on day 20 as well and vice versa. I use the datepicker. Remembering that it is not to update an input but rather the calendar itself. Sorry for English, because I'm using google translator.

Comment: Summarizing to improve the explanation:
When clicking on the calendar that is at the top of the figure that you see from **5 to 11** (**7 days a week**), this should send the day clicked to the calendar below that is currently marked on the **25th**. Then if I clicked on **8** as the example below should be marked **8** as well. I hope I have helped in the explanation, because I need it urgently and I am not finding a way to do this since I do not have much experience in javascript or jquery.